# html5 canvas animation does not work properly

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop, html5-canvas

All the javascript is in `style.js` - http://html5canvas.hoangminhdat.com

You can see that the blue line appears when the page load and quickly disappear after a certain amount of time. I've spent hours and, have done everything I can to debug it but nothing I change fixed it.

This is what I did:

1. I use global variables to create the red line.
2. I get rid of the global variables and create a class (Circle). I store the objects in an array (circles) and use those objects' properties instead of the variables.
3. I successfully apply for the first element of the "circles" array (circles[0]). I added circles[1]. And the blue line actually appears in the canvas for roughly 1 second, and then it disappears...

I can't find any mistake in my code. Since the `circles[0]` works, and the `circles[1]` works for a little while when the page load. I believe that my code is fully functioning.

Well, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some error in your loop

> ```
> //use the position to make dots
> for (var i in points[j]) { ... }
> ```

It is throwing lots of errors.

I haven't gone into detail, but it is looking for some extra item in the array. You can see your example working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/hnPf2/2/) with this change

> ```
> //use the position to make dots
> var numPoints = points[j].length-1, i;
> for (i = 0;i<numPoints;i++) {
> ```

Maybe you can go from there to identify what was exactly wrong in all your code...

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!, that's why there's a strange dot that follow my path when I set fade out effect the first time.. Even though I don't really know why is that, thank you soooo much!!!